# How can I prevent users from overwriting databases when restoring?

Tags: sql-server

I don't want users to restore (with overwrite) on some specific databases. How can I inhibit from restoring over these databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want users to be able to restore databases from existing backup files, but only to new names.

I actually wouldn't give them permissions to restore databases at all - instead, create a stored procedure that will do the restores, and then grant permissions to the stored procedure rather than the user. [Erland Sommarskog's article on granting permissions via certificates](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates) is fantastic. In a nutshell, you're going to:

- Create a certificate
- Create a login for that certificate
- Grant the permissions to do restores to that login
- Create a stored procedure with your own logic in it
- Sign the stored proc with the certificate
- Grant the users permissions to run the stored proc

It's way easier than it sounds. Then your stored procedure can have the business logic to check to make sure the database doesn't exist, plus you can put in more stuff like checking that there's enough drive space to safely restore the database, that they're putting it on the right drives, etc.

I can imagine even coding in a max number of databases that can be restored - for example, once we've hit 50 restored databases, don't allow any more - it's time for the user to clean house.

The stored proc would have input parameters for backup file, target database name, and folder path(s) for the restored files. You might find the logic in the [MSSQLtips post on automatically generating restore scripts](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1584/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script-from-backup-files-in-a-directory/) useful too - point it at a folder, and it gets the latest full, diff, and t-log backups and generates the restore statements.

Answer (score 5):

If what you're asking is how to prevent a login from restoring over an existing database, then take a look at [this reference on BOL for `RESTORE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

> ## Permissions
>
> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. **If the**
>    **database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the**
>    **sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the**
>    **database** (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information
>   is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role
>   membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and
>   undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed,
>   members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE
>   permissions.

In your case, it sounds like the database exists and users are restoring over it.  In that case, just reiterating what permissions are *required*, you will need to ensure that your particular logins aren't sysadmin or dbcreator members along with the owner of the database.

What it boils down to is, if you don't want people to be able to carry out certain operations, don't give them the permissions to do such.